# How to overlay graphical effects on top of a 2D text game (akin to a terminal emulator)?

Tags: python, qt, opengl, python-3.x, sdl-2

I'm developing a story-heavy 2D game with a canvas akin to a terminal emulator and I would like to incorporate graphical effects (such as the distortions of an old TV screen). All existing components are written in Python 3.4 and the game should be platform independent (I work on a Mac). Performance is not critical. It consists of a main window that contains:

- The terminal interface (this is where the game happens)
- A menu overlay (handles load/save features as well as options, etc.)
- A graphical overlay that renders graphical effects on top of the other output.

So far, I have made two attempts at a solution, one with `Qt5` and the other with `SDL2`, but I would prefer to discuss the `Qt5` approach. Using `Qt5`, I've managed to implement the terminal interface (`QTextEdit`) and the menu overlay (`QGraphicsView`), but I fail to integrate the graphical effect overlay. My ideas were `OpenGL`shaders or `QGraphicsEffect`, the latter of which does not work on Mac OS X.

I have been using `vispy.gloo`for my `OpenGL` calls and using the `SDL2` approach, I was able to get a working shader-based implementation of the graphical effects.

Based on http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34245-Render-QWidget-within-QGLWidget I have tried to incorporate these effects into a `QMainWindow` as an overlay to existing content (see code example below does not include any graphics effects) but first of all, the post does not really address my issue and secondly, I get a known bug of `Qt5`(https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32639?attachmentOrder=desc).

I would be grateful for ideas to possible working implementations of the graphical effects and I'm open to suggestions of new frameworks. Thanks so much!

**Code example of Qt5 implementation:**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  # {{{1
    """Extension of the QMainWindow class."""

    def __init__(self, central=None, overlay=None, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent

        # For readability of the output, set a minimum size
        self.setMinimumSize(680, 480)

        # Create the central widget containing the terminal and focus
        self.widget = central  # Instance of QTextEdit
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setFocusProxy(self.widget)

        # Create the menu overlay
        self.menu_overlay = overlay  # Instance of QGraphicsView
        self.menu_overlay.setParent(self)

        # Here, I would like to add the graphics effect (old TV screen) overlaid
        # on top of the central widget and the menu overlay. The g-e have to be
        # transparent to keyboard and mouse events.

        # Resize and show the main window.
        self.resize(1024, 768)
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        """Resizes all child widgets that are not automatically resized (e.g. overlays)."""
        pass
```

Comment: This sound to be an interesting _project_. And [we'd love to help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But to match with StackOverflow format, you should try to split that to _individual/well focused_ issues. May I suggest you to take a look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ too ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The reason why I created a rather general and complex question is because I cannot find a way to unify my individual points, despite being able to create the features individually under some circumstances. I'll adapt the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to devise a solution to my issue. Unfortunately, I had to move away from Python towards QML for the implementation of the graphical effect.

Based on the Qt tutorial for QtQuick (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-shadereffects-example.html), the following snippet creates an OpenGL shader effect that takes its input from another QML element:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    id: win
    visible: Window.AutomaticVisibility
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: theItem
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        // [...] your content here
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: theSource
        sourceItem: theItem
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id: shader
        anchors.centerIn: theItem
        width: theItem.width
        height: theItem.height
        property variant u_sampler: theSource
        fragmentShader:
            // [...] any shader program using the following parameters:
            "uniform float qt_Opacity;" +
            "uniform sampler2D u_sampler;" +
            "varying vec2 qt_TexCoord0;" +
            "void main(void) {" +
            "    vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler, qt_TexCoord0);" +
            "    color.a = qt_Opacity;" +
            "    gl_FragColor = color;" +
            "}"
    }
}
```